# Correct terminology to write Jacobian Matrices

Tags: notation, jacobian

I need to write in my report jacobian matrices, however don't know if it should be,

J(S,E,I,R)= ... jacobian matrix of system (no values yet subtituted in) ...

or

J($S^* ,E^* ,I^* ,R^*$)= ..... jacobian matrix of system (no values yet subtituted in) ...

where ($S^* ,E^* ,I^* ,R^*$) represent the equilibrium point for the model?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Changed - thanks!